# Using RestTemplate with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, rest

I am working on a project in which I need to make an HTTP URL call to my server, running RESTful service, which returns the response as a `JSON` String. I am using `RestTemplate` here along with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` to execute a URL.

I have set up an HTTP request timeout (`READ` and `CONNECTION` time out) on my `RestTemplate` by using `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

Here is my main code which is using the future and callables:

```
public class TimeoutThreadExample {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    // does it have to be static final?
    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = createRestTemplate();

    // does this look right with the way I am creating `RestTemplate`?
    private static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(){
        // is it ok to create a new instance of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory everytime?
       HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
       requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
       requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
       return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
     }

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(restTemplate));
        String response = null;

        try {
            response = future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Task` class which implements the `Callable` interface and uses the `RestTemplate`:

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url";
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Now I have everything working in my above code. Is the way I am creating `RestTemplate` along with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` thread-safe and efficient? Since `RestTemplate` is very heavy to be created so not sure whether I have it right or not. I'd like to improve anything in creation of `RestTemplate` with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will you have many instances of `TimeoutThreadExample` in your real application? If not, then the `restTemplate` field will be better non-static, initialized in the constructor:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

public TimeoutThreadExample() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

On the other hand, if you will have many instances of `TimeoutThreadExample`, then it will be better to make `restTemplate` static, and initialize it in a static initializer block instead of using a method:

```
private static final RestTemplate restTemplate;

static {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

As for this question:

> // is it ok to create a new instance of HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory everytime?

In both alternatives I offered, the instance is really created only once, so that's ok.

> The way I am creating RestTemplate along with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory is thread safe and efficient?

Initializing static variables is thread safe. And since you're creating `RestTemplate` and `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` only once, it's efficient too.

Answer (score 3):

### What properties should be static?

As a rule of thumb; *Do not use static properties*. If you ask yourself "Should I use `static` here?", then you shouldn't. In other words; if it is not a constant, it need not be static either. You asked "does it have to be static final?", in general if a property is `static` it also needs to be `final`. However, having a single object shared across multiple objects is not a reason (excuse) to use static properties.

Static properties increases the coupling of component.

### What to do?

Use Dependency Injection. Especially if you are using **Spring** you **should** use dependency injection. Spring framework libraries are designed to be used that way.

### Other points

Follow [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Concretely: first write the interface you need, then write an implementation.

Do not swallow exceptions, `printStackTrace` is not proper exception handling.

Do not use local variables unnecessarily, it impedes readability.

Return early from a method (`getData()`), do not contort your method's body to make it have a single `return`.

I assume you know what you are doing by creating a `Future` and immediately calling `get`.

### Refactored Code

Create your component interface, name it according to what it does, not how it does it:

```
public interface DataGetterDAO {
    String getData();
}
```

Create your component interface, You can name it according to how it does its work, it that's what sets this implementation apart:

```
public class DataGetterDAORestImpl implements DataGetterDAO {
    // this could be injected also.
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public DataGetterDAORestImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return restTemplate.getForObject("some_url", String.class);
            }
        });

        try {
            return future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("some message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for *using* an object **does not** belong in that object. Because an object **should not** constrain how itself is *used*. Object construction and wire-up is such a case of *use*.

For example above component can be constructed as below, (obtained by moving the rest of the code you supplied):

```
public class ApplicationWireup {
    void init() {
       HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
       requestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIME_OUT);
       requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

       DataGetterDAO dataGetterDAO = new DataGetterDAORestImpl(restTemplate);

       // inject dataGetterDAO to services that need it.
    }
}
```

or using spring configuration xmls, or annotations, or some other DI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Why not configuring a proper restTemplate with everything you need?

[See here](http://blog.modernjava.info/2013/06/restful-service-configuration-for.html) - it uses [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) where you can configure the number of connections (and remove your thread executor), also read/connect timeouts and many useful stuff.

This way you will make the code much cleaner.